# How to export ruTorrent trt table to rss

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

I own a seedbox which has ruTorrent installed. The ruTorrent is a web UI for torrent downloading (for those who don't know).

After I log in, it creates a table and it populates it with a "trt" array. I want to make an RSS feed that takes a label variable filters through the trt array and outputs all the torrents in an XML RSS feed format.

It would take the label via URL so something like

index?label=blahblah etc.

The only issue is that I have no idea how to access the trt array directly or where all the information is stored. I can only access it when the table is loaded. Here is my javascript so far which takes the label filters it and puts the torrent information accordingly. Now how could I make this into an RSS feed?

```
for(var k in theWebUI.torrents){
    var x = "<?php echo $_GET["label"];?>";
    var table = theWebUI.getTable("trt");
    var rss = "Nothing";
    if(table.getValueById(k, "label").toLowerCase() == x){
        rss = "label:" + table.getValueById(k, "label").toLowerCase() + ":label";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Google? ruTorrent already has an RSS plugin...

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to do the opposite of the plugin, I'm trying to create an RSS feed out of my own downloads/torrents instead of making it download from an RSS feed.